# Custom Wordpress Editor?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

After looking around for hours I couldn't see anything even close to what I saw here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Bu5NoYZ7M&feature=player_embedded

As you can see, they created a custom editor for Wordpress (not just some edits to TinyMCE), its a whole different editor even with an option to switch back to TinyMCE.

Does anyone know how to create custom editors for wordpress without altering the core files and just via a custom theme? I am starting to think its a custom meta box...but I am not sure.

Any clue will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a plugin to extend the default tinymce WP uses..  Take a look at this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-edit/screenshots/

If you really want a completely different editor, ckeditor is quite ok.. There is a plugin too: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/screenshots/

Always use or write a plugin an don't change any core files is indeed the way to go!

Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Hey quokka thanks for your answer. Do you know what hook can actually let me customize the editor? Have you seen any documentation around?
Thanks!